# How does Parse measure active users?

Tags: parse-platform

I was wondering how does parse rack these users? I'm developing an app with 2 other people right now, but parse is showing 19 installations and 5 monthly active users. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new installation corresponds to your app's user allowing push notifications when you ask. Every new app re-install also counts as a new installation. So if during testing you install/re-install quite a bit, this will go up.

An active user corresponds to a user who's logged in via your app. It depends on how you're testing and your login mechanism.

Monthly active, I believe refers to the activity over the last 30 days.